# NHibernate Load vs. Get behavior for testing

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate

In simple tests I can assert whether an object has been persisted by whether it's Id is no longer at it's default value. But delete an object and want to check whether the object and perhaps its children are *really* not in the database, the object Id's will still be at their saved values.

So I need to go to the db, and I would like a helper assertion to make the tests more readable, which is where the question comes in. I like the idea of using Load to save the db call, but I'm wondering if the ensuing exceptions can corrupt the session.

Below are how the two assertions would look, I think. Which would you use?

Cheers,
Berryl

## Get

```
public static void AssertIsTransient<T>(this T instance, ISession session)
    where T : Entity
{
    if (instance.IsTransient()) return; 

    var found = session.Get<T>(instance.Id);
    if (found != null) Assert.Fail(string.Format("{0} has persistent id '{1}'", instance, instance.Id));
}
```

## Load

```
public static void AssertIsTransient<T>(this T instance, ISession session)
    where T : Entity
{
    if (instance.IsTransient()) return; 

    try
    {
        var found = session.Load<T>(instance.Id);
        if (found != null) Assert.Fail(string.Format("{0} has persistent id '{1}'", instance, instance.Id));
    }
    catch (GenericADOException)
    {
        // nothing
    }
    catch (ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

## edit

In either case I would be doing the fetch (Get or Load) in a new session, free of state from the session that did the save or delete.

I am trying to test cascade behavior, NOT to test NHib's ability to delete things, but maybe I am over thinking this one or there is a simpler way I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 6):

Your code in the 'Load'-section will always hit Assert.Fail, but never throw an exception as `Load<T>` will return a proxy (with the Id-property set - or populated from the 1st level cache) without hitting the DB - ie. ISession.Load will only fail, if you access a property other than your Id-property on a deleted entity.

As for your 'Get'-section - I might be mistaken, but I think that if you delete an entity in a session - and later try to use .Get in the same session - you will get the one in 1st level cache - and again not return null.

See this [post](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) for the full explanation about .Load and .Get.

If you really need to see if it is in your DB - use a IStatelessSession - or launch a child-ISession (which will have an empty 1st level cache.

EDIT: I thought of a bigger problem - your entity will first be deleted when the transaction is committed (when the session is flushed per default) - so unless you manually flush your session (not recommended), you will still have it in your DB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: also could do `session.Clear()` or `session.Evict(entity)`

Comment: He would still need to commit his transaction before doing that.

Comment: @Goblin. You are right about the Get, and what I do is effectively to clear and close the save/ delete session before using either a Get (I would think this is a fairly common test scenario)

Comment: I would think this is a fairly common test scenario when you have a non-trivial object graph with cascades. Doesn't anyone else do something like this?

Comment: I never test 3rd party libraries like that. Instead I enforce it in the DB (not-null foreign-keys) so it will throw an exception if a cascade isn't correctly set up in the ORM. And since I am working on financial ERP solutions - delete isn't an option :-).